# Eclipse luna 64b does not start (java 8u20 64b unzipped, win7 64b)

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit, java-8, startup

I'm trying to start to develop a PHP/js app in eclipse, but I can't make it start on my computer.

I'm working on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, and I have admin rights (It's a corporate computer).

I downloaded the JDK version 8u20 64b exe, and opened it with 7zip. I copied all the files that were inside in D:\jdk8_20 (example).

I downloaded eclipse from the website (latest version Luna, 64bit), and unzipped it on my desktop.

I modified the eclipse.ini to tell eclipse to use the unzipped JVM.
It did not work (Java exited with -1 code) with the following argument :

```
-vm
D:\javapath\bin\javaw.exe
```

So i used (as advised by http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example) this argument :

```
-vm
D:\javapath\jre\server\java.dll
```

Now i can see, when i start exlipse.exe with or without admin rights, the Eclipse logo page (the one that show the loading process at the very beginning) very shortly, then nothing more.
No eclipse nor java process is running after that.

Does anyone know/have an idea of what I did wrong?

I cannot install java in the usual way, as I use corporate applications that require Java 6.

Comment: Did you check whether Eclipse created any log files?

Comment: I tried to add -consoleLog in the eclipse.ini and start it from  cmd, but nothing gets displayed. I do not see any log files in the eclipse folders. Any idea of where i can find the logs ?

Comment: look in workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: As i never managed to start eclipse, i never set any workspace. Is there a default place where they are written when no workspace is known ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.
I installed Java 8, then unactivated it in the control panel, and i still use my -vm arg in eclipse.ini.

This allows me to keep my 6u23 running as usual for corporate applications, and link to my 8u20 when i want.

I assume that Java 8 do need some installed component (like mission control) for running.

Anyway, many thanks for your help :)